# "e.TotalManipulation.Translation" not consistent when swiping

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm having some issues with a page I'm developing in WP7. Basically, I want to "swipe" right and left and have something else come into view. However, when swiping (either in the emulator or on a device), the `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(delta.X.ToString)` can report opposite values (thus resulting in the wrong swipe). So I swipe right and it reports something like "-15" and then I swipe right again and it reports "15". One is right and the other isn't, but my finger gesture is identical both times.

What could be causing this? Here's my code. I've tested it in another app and it works with no problems. So now this has got me wondering what could cause it to report drastically different numbers (again, resulting in the wrong action that is desired).

```
Private Sub PlayerArea_ManipulationCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.IsInertial Then
        e.Handled = True
        Dim delta As Point = e.TotalManipulation.Translation
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(delta.X.ToString)
        If delta.X < 0.0 Then
            p.MoveNext()
        ElseIf delta.X > 0.0 Then
            p.MoveBack()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Does anyone else have this issue? I've found nothing on all of Binglehoo that even mentions someone else with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to do this manually, you can use the [HorizontalDrag gesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967546%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) from the XNA assembly.